Composition of constrained existentials
Let's posit two "generic protocols", using the new (Swift 5.7) syntax:
@MainActor
protocol P1<T>: AnyObject {
    associatedtype T
    func f1(_: T)
}

@MainActor
protocol P2<U>: AnyObject {
    associatedtype U
    func f2(_: U)
}

Now, in a type, I can declare, as the types of properties, existentials that resolve the "generic", using generic-style syntax:
class MyClass {
    var myP1Property: (any P1<Int>)? // ok
    var myP2Property: (any P2<String>)? // ok
}

Cool. Now I want to declare a property whose type is a composition of those two types with those resolutions:
class MyClass {
    var myP1P2Property: (any P1<Int> & P2<String>)? // error
}

That doesn't compile, and I find the error message mysterious: "Non-protocol, non-class type ... cannot be used within a protocol-constrained type."
Now, we are not without recourse in this situation. Instead of using the compose operator, I can declare another protocol which, in effect, performs the same composition:
@MainActor
protocol P1P2<T, U>: P1, P2 {}

This solves the problem; in my class, I can now say
class MyClass {
    var myP1P2Property: (any P1P2<Int, String>)? // ok
}

That accomplishes exactly what I wanted to accomplish, so there's no real problem here. But is there in fact a way to do it the first way, with composition — some way that I'm not finding? And if not, isn't this kind of a hole in the language?

typealias X = P1<Int> & P2<String> then var myP1P2Property: (any X)? works. Do note that the two approach you mentioned are semantically different. A type might conform to P1 and P2, but not P1P2.

Absolutely. — So you can say it with composition in a typealias but not in a property declaration? Don't you think that's kind of weird?

I agree it's a bit weird. I can't say anything else about it though.

Well, I'll submit this one myself, said the Little Red Hen: https://github.com/swiftlang/swift/issues/77432

Confirmed by Apple as a known bug; see https://github.com/swiftlang/swift/issues/63877. @RobNapier got in ahead of me on this one!

@RobNapier taking your name in vain here. :)
